# Linq ToDictionary() Implementation

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have List as follows:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "Bob",LastName="test",EMPID="1234" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Bob",LastName="t",EMPID="1234" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Jane",LastName="test",EMPID="1234" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Jane",LastName="t",EMPID="1234" }
};
```

Here all the person fields are unique if add FirstName and LastName.

If I Use

```
  Dictionary<string, Person> dictionary = people.ToDictionary(v => v.FirstName);
```

then I will get Item already exist exception.

and even I can't use LastName aswell.

so I need to use combination of FirstName and the LastName and that value can be saved as FirstName;#LastName in the Dictionary Key

I am very new to C# development

Any suggestions are really helpful.

Regards

Anand

Comment: Make your `EMPID` unique, that should be its purpose to begin with.

Comment: also how can or should i ask why would 2 different employee's share the same EMPID..

Answer (score 3):

You can use all kinds of expressions inside a LINQ delegate.
Try

```
 Dictionary<string, Person> dictionary = people.ToDictionary(v => v.FirstName + ";#" + v.LastName);
```

Comment: This allows for potential collisions between users that have different names.

Comment: @Servy are you sure? If they have different names (like the OP assumes) then the resulting keys are definitely distinct.

Comment: Glorfindel, I think the OP's assumption is definitely wrong, (i.e John Smith is very common etc)

Comment: I agree with that. I hope he has other means to guarantee that the names are unique. Maybe it's a small company :)

Comment: @Glorfindel The names {"A;#B","C"} and {"A", "B#;C"} will collide with each other in your solution, despite being distinct.  That combined with the point Sayse has made that names are not necessarily unique identifiers of people in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Then the names should be checked for certain non-alphanumeric characters: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Glorfindel The whole moral of SQL injection attacks in the first place is not to sanitize input, but rather to wire the code such that the strings are actually treated as data, regardless of their content.  Rather than concatting the strings together you should write a solution that doesn't care what the strings are, and that can support any strings, regardless of what characters they do or don't have.  It's pretty trivial to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a key that is unique (or don't want to use that key for a dictionary), there are other alternative than `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.`

For example, you could create a lookup:

```
people.ToLookup(v => v.FirstName);
```

A lookup accept to have more than one match for each key (in fact it is its only purpose). It can then be accessed like a dictionary, but it will return an enumeration instead of a single value:

```
var lookup = people.ToLookup(v => v.FirstName);
var johns = lookup["John"];
foreach (var john in johns)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(john.ToString());
}
```

You could also use linq's `GroupBy` extension which purpose is closely related to lookup, but iteration is different. Plus you can discover the keys while iterating (which is not the case with lookup where you need to know the keys in advance):

```
var groups = people.GroupBy(v => v.FirstName);
foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    var key = grp.Key;
    foreach (var person in grp)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(person.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `GetHashCode` is for - [read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It does not have to be unique, and any two that are the same is no guarantee of equality.  And it is used with `Equals`, which you haven't overridden.  And neither seem relevant to the problem.